# Named alternates between working for example.com & www.example.com

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, web-hosting, domain-name, bind

I have a domain registered with [eNom](http://enom.com). From time to time I will do an `nslookup  example.com` and get the IP address. However, when I put `nslookup  www.example.com` it responds

> can't find www.example.com: server failed

After restarting Named, I get this error for `example.com`, while `www.example.com` is working as expected.

What could be causing this issue?

I am restarting the main name server in our network; the mentioned domain is hosted on another server.

Comment: Could you edit you question to include your zone file and named's error log ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare your www subdomain as a CNAME to your A - example of bind9 configs below:

--- named.conf

```
*SNIP*
zone "domainname.com" {
     type master;
     file "/etc/bind/domainname.com";
     allow-update { none; };
};
```

--- /etc/bind/domainname.com

```
*SNIP*
@       IN      A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
www     IN      CNAME   @
```

Notes:

- xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is your IP address (for the domain)
- there are some parts missing from configs (in the place of *SNIP*); added only the interesting bits

Kaplah.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually got a www in your zone file? Just having the name (and the root working) isn't enough to make the www sub domain work.

Comment: The question is quite clear (and will be more clear once my edit goes through) that the www subdomain does work ... sometimes.